# Perl Text::CSV_XS | getline() is combining lines

Tags: csv, perl

I'm using the `Text::CSV_XS` module to read in a csv file for further processing. I've been hitting a wall while attempting to load the lines into a sql server db and I've isolated the issue to the `Text::CSV_XS` module, and specifically `getline()`.

`getline` seems to be combining two lines, resulting in an incorrect field count (24 columns, but getting 48 fields). I've reviewed the raw data and found one line is missing it's last value.

Here's a condensed example:

```
RowNum , Firstname ,  Lastname ,  EmailAddress
-------------------------------
1      , Joe       ,  Schmo    ,  "Joe.Schmo@email.com"\n
2      , Edgar     ,  Elbows   ,  \n
3      , Amanda    ,  Ankles   ,  "Amanda.Ankles@email.com"\n
```

This is what the issue looks like after it's been read in:

`'1','Joe','Schmo','Joe.Schmo@email.com'`

`'2','Edgar','Elbows','3','Amanda','Ankles','Amanda.Ankles@email.com'`

=====================

In short, getline, by default is looking for unquoted `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`, to determine `eol`. From what I can tell, it seems like the `,\n` is resulting in a lost field and an incorrect field/column count. I know how to fix this AFTER the lines are read, but not before. I'll continue to trouble-shoot and update if I find any solutions.

As requested, here is the `Text::CSV_XS` constructor:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ 
                             binary          => 1,
                             always_quote    => 1,
                             verbatim        => 1,
                             skip_empty_rows => 1 
                             });
```

*Unfortunately, I'm not able to supply a copy of the data I'm working with.*

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of the Perl script you use to parse the input file? Specifically which parameters you pass to the constructor in `Text::CSV_XS`. It would also be helpful if you could upload the input file somewhere, then we could try to reproduce.

Comment: For some reason when I run this, my CSV_XS does not recognize the attribute `skip_empty_rows`. When I remove that attribute, the code runs without issue with the given input.

Comment: @TLP Interesting! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @TLP Good catch! I think that solved it. Looking at the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#skip_empty_rows) I'm now seeing that `skip_empty_rows` attribute is intended to be used with the parse method, which i am not using in this script. 

Feel free to submit that as the answer, and I'll mark it as such. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @THANOS--WAS--RIGHT Actually, the constructor statement fails, and the `$csv` object is undefined. It fails before it reaches getline(), so it cannot be because of parsing. It is probably some version issue, or some other undocumented synergy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding speculation in comments as answer, as requested.

For some reason when I run this, my CSV_XS does not recognize the attribute [`skip_empty_rows`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#skip_empty_rows). When I remove that attribute, the code runs without issue with the given input.

The attribute is supposedly only used with parsing, but it causes the creation of the csv object to fail before any functions are applied. If I were to guess, I would think it is a version issue, where our version does not include this attribute `skip_empty_rows`. I get this error with the `error_diag` function:

```
# CSV_XS ERROR: 1000 - INI - Unknown attribute 'skip_empty_rows' @ rec 0 pos 0
Can't call method "getline" on an undefined value at foo.pl line 15.
```

Code:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ 
        binary          => 1,
        always_quote    => 1,
        verbatim        => 1,
        skip_empty_rows => 1,
    }) or Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();
```

Update:

My assumption was correct, the `skip_empty_rows` attribute was introduced with version 1.46 -- the latest version -- and my version is 1.44. Below is the [ChangeLog for Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/dist/Text-CSV_XS/changes):

```
1.46    - 2021-03-24, H.Merijn Brand
    * It's 2021
    * New attribute comment_str     (RFC 4180-bis)
    * New attribute skip_empty_rows (RFC 4180-bis)
    * http -> https in links in docs
    * Fix several issues with auto-detecting \r as EOL
    * Tested on perl-5.6.1 .. perl-5.32.1 and perl-5.33.8 (145)
```